# Setting margins on a textView on a fragment in kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, textview, margins

I am trying to create TextVIew margins in kotlin inside of a fragment. For some reason the parameters are null and the program crashes when the fragment gets executed.

Printing the actual text works, it's just when I try to create margins, it won't work. I've tried placing safe null checks to allow nulls but ultimately ended with an null exception.

```
val textView = TextView(activity)
textView.text = "Overall Rating: $overall_rating\n$comments  \n" +
    " Will live again: $willLiveAgain\nTimestamp: ${timestamp.toDate()}\n"

var params = textView.layoutParams as? LinearLayout.LayoutParams
params?.setMargins(48,10,48,10)
textView.id=1
textView.layoutParams = params  //nullpointer exception
```

> 2019-07-08 23:50:26.021 2332-2332/com.example.cribb E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.cribb, PID: 2332
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Layout parameters cannot be null
>           at android.view.View.setLayoutParams(View.java:16088)
>           at com.example.cribb.DisplayListingFragment$showReviews$1.onSuccess(DisplayListingFragment.kt:95)
>           at com.example.cribb.DisplayListingFragment$showReviews$1.onSuccess(DisplayListingFragment.kt:32)
>           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzn.run(Unknown Source:4)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>   2019-07-08 23:50:26.039 2332-2332/com.example.cribb I/Process: Sending
>   signal. PID: 2332 SIG: 9

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation:

You've hidden your problem with `?`.
Operators that consist of `?` need to be used with care.

#### Operator `as?`

```
var params = textView.layoutParams as? LinearLayout.LayoutParams
```

`as?` will return `null` if `textView.layoutParams` return `null`.
After this call your `params` variable equals `null`.

#### Operator `?.`

```
params?.setMargins(48,10,48,10)
```

This is equal to:

```
if (params != null) {
    params.setMargins(48, 10, 48, 10)
}
```

In your case `params==null` so nothing is executed.

#### `setLayoutParams` call (using property syntax)

The `setLayoutParams` method requires you to pass `non-null` `LayoutParams` argument. From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams)):

> `ViewGroup.LayoutParams`: The layout parameters for this view, **cannot be null**

That's why when you pass `params==null` your app crashes.

---

#### Why `textView.layoutParams` returns `null`

From [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#getLayoutParams()):

> The `LayoutParams` associated with this view, **or null if no parameters have been set yet**

You're calling `textView.layoutParams` for a `View` that was created manually (not through `xml` layout), with:

```
val textView = TextView(activity)
```

`layoutParams` field says how a particular `view` is attached to the **enclosing layout**. So if you've created your `View` programmatically and you have not attached it to any `ViewGroup` (e.g. `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, `ConstraintLayout`, etc.) the `getLayoutParams` will return `null` because there is no **enclosing layout** for your `View`.

#### How to fix that?

Either add your *programmatically* created `View` to a `ViewGroup` using (one of) [`addView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/view/ViewGroup?hl=en#addview) method(s), or create your `View` in a layout xml file and put it inside a `ViewGroup` there.